# (regex) How do I capture all data between brackets when one event log contains 5 fields and the other contains 6?

Tags: regex, pcre

I have the following logs I am trying to parse correctly:

```
[groupA] [groupB] [groupC] [groupD] [groupE] messsage
```

`[groupA] [groupB] [groupC] [groupD] [groupE] [groupF] messsage`

Some of the events have 5 bracketed fields and 1 message, and the other set of logs contain 6 bracketed fields and 1 message.

How do I capture (and name) each field within the brackets? I have the following regex that captures the first layout and then I do an OR (|) that captures the second layout:

```
\[(?<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\,\d{3})\]\s\[(?<A>.+?)\]\s\[(?<B>.+?)\]\s\[(?<C>.+?)\]\s\[(?<D>.+?)\]\s(?<message>.*)|\[(?<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\,\d{3})\]\s\[(?<A>.+?)\]\s\[(?<B>.+?)\]\s\[(?<C>.+?)\]\s\[(?<D>.+?)\]\s\[(?<E>.+?)\]\s(?<message>.*)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an optional group like this:

```
\[(?<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\,\d{3})\]
  \s\[(?<A>.+?)]
  \s\[(?<B>.+?)]
  \s\[(?<C>.+?)]
  \s\[(?<D>.+?)]
  (?:\s\[(?<E>.+?)])? # HERE
\s(?<message>.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kU8eI1/1) (I used `\h` in the multiline demo to exclude `\n` from matching with `\s`).

Also, to allow empty values, replace `.+?` with `.*?`. If the values inside `[...]` do not contain `]`  nor `[`, I advise replacing all `\[(.+?)]` with `\[([^][]*)]`.

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much. I've never used the optional grouping.

Answer (score 0):

This regex seeems to work for your situation. I have tested it with pcre and with your two sample inputs.

```
/\[([a-zA-Z]+)+\]|([a-zA-Z]+)/g
```